# HTML CSS and JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment where I need to make the cloud that appears at the top change to either a freezing face emoji or a sun depending on the temperature. I have the Java set up so when the prompts pop up, the city and temperature change based on the user's responses.

1. How do I change the existing emoji to the new ones?
2. The new h1 shows the entries for the prompt but they are not spaced. How do I create spacing between the words?

   Weather App
        
          h1,
          h2,
          h3 {
            text-align: center;
            font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
          }

   ```
      h1 {
        color: #1a64d6;
        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 48px;
        margin: 0;
      }

      h2 {
        margin: 0;

        font-size: 34px;
        line-height: 48px;
        font-weight: 400;
      }

      ul {
        padding: 0;
      }

      li {
        list-style: none;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 10px 0;
        border-radius: 10px;
        transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
        max-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
      }

      li:hover {
        background: #fffbef;
      }

      p {
        font-size: 18px;
        opacity: 0.7;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: monospace;
      }

      button {
        display: block;
        margin: 20px auto;
        border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
        background: #1a64d6;
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 16px;
        line-height: 22px;
        padding: 16px 24px;
        border-radius: 30px;
        transition: all 200ms ease;
        box-shadow: rgba(37, 39, 89, 0.08) 0px 8px 8px 0;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      button:hover {
        background: white;
        color: #1a64d6;
        border: 1px solid #1a64d6;
      }
    </style>
   ```

   ## Currently 21° in Tokyo

   ### 13° / **23°**

   - #### Tomorrow

     10° / **22°**
   - #### Saturday

     15° / **17°**
   - #### ☀️ Sunday

     25° / **28°**

   ```
    <button>Change city</button>
    <p>Coded by Matt Delac</p>
    <script>
      function city() {
        let cityName = prompt("What city do you live in?");
        let temp = prompt("What temperature is it?");
        let heading = document.querySelector("h1");

        if (temp <= 0) {
          heading.innerHTML = "Currently" + temp + "in" + cityName;
        } else {
          heading.innerHTML = "Currently" + temp + "in" + cityName;
        }
      }

      let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
      changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", city);
    </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution to Question 1

To change the emoji just change the `alt` and `src` attribute on an `img` tag.

Here is the code

```js
  function city() {
     let cityName = prompt("What city do you live in?");
     let temp = prompt("What temperature is it?");
     let heading = document.querySelector("h1");
     let img = document.querySelector('img');

     if (temp <= 0) {
       heading.innerHTML = "Currently " + temp + "in" + cityName;
       img.setAttribute('alt', 'freezing emoji');
       img.setAttribute('src', 'path/to.emoji');
     } else {
       heading.innerHTML = "Currently" + temp + "in" + cityName;
       img.setAttribute('alt', 'not freezing emoji');
       img.setAttribute('src', 'path/to.emoji');
     }
   }

   let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
   changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", city);
```

### Solution to Question 2

All you need to do to add spacing is to add spaces to the end of the strings.

The JS would look like this

```js
    function city() {
     let cityName = prompt("What city do you live in?");
     let temp = prompt("What temperature is it?");
     let heading = document.querySelector("h1");
     let img = document.querySelector('img');

     if (temp <= 0) {
       heading.innerHTML = "Currently " + temp + " in " + cityName;
       img.setAttribute('alt', 'freezing emoji');
       img.setAttribute('src', 'path/to.emoji');
     } else {
       heading.innerHTML = "Currently " + temp + " in " + cityName;
       img.setAttribute('alt', 'not freezing emoji');
       img.setAttribute('src', 'path/to.emoji');
     }
   }

   let changeCityButton = document.querySelector("button");
   changeCityButton.addEventListener("click", city);
```

[Here is the link to the codepen.](https://codepen.io/bobsfriend/pen/KKaVWmP)